# Why can't I save csv as a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, heat-map

I am trying to follow the instructions given here, [Tutorial: Making Heatmaps using QGIS and GRASS](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/07/tutorial-making-heatmaps-using-qgis-and.html) ,  to build a heat map with my own data. I taken the first step and imported a csv data table into the layer bar, but when I attempt to save it as a shapefile, QGIS tells me that is not a valid or recognized data source. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Shapefiles use an old DBF standard for the attribute table, which means column names are limited. Make sure your column headings don't have spaces or special characters, and are not longer than 10 characters.

Comment: I managed to get it saved to a Shapefile by using the Add Delimited Text plugin. Result!!

Comment: @BenWells I suggest then adding this as a solution to the question and marking as correct, so the next person to come along can easily find the answer. Also, what GeoKevin said is 100% correct, so make sure to reference his answer also!

Comment: @om_henners OK, can you tell me how I add this as a solution? I cant see any means of doing this. Thanks

Comment: There should be an "Add Answer" or "Answer This Question" button below these comments. Click that and type your answer in. You'll be able to accept that answer later (there will be a grey checkmark below the up/down vote buttons).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it saved to a Shapefile by using the Add Delimited Text plugin.